# npm install @discord/js not working on amazon aws ec2 linux system

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, discord.js

I'm hosting a discord bot on amazon aws ec2 but its giving me an error saying that it cant find opus modules like node-opus and @discordjs/opus so when I try installing with npm install @discordjs/opus it gives me a huge error. I've been trying to figure it out for a day but I can't understand why it installed and worked perfectly on windows but not on linux. The entire code and music player works on windows but on linux it can't install opus module.
error message:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/build'
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_multistream.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_projection_encoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/analysis.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/mlp_data.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_multistream_encoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_projection_decoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/mapping_matrix.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_compare.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/mlp.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_multistream_decoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_decoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/repacketizer.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/src/opus_encoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decode_frame.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/inner_product_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/scale_vector_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/find_pred_coefs_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/schur_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/warped_autocorrelation_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/burg_modified_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/find_LPC_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/LPC_inv_pred_gain_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/scale_copy_vector_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/noise_shape_analysis_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/pitch_analysis_core_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/bwexpander_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/LTP_analysis_filter_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/LTP_scale_ctrl_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/corrMatrix_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/encode_frame_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/sort_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/find_pitch_lags_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/residual_energy_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/LPC_analysis_filter_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/autocorrelation_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/k2a_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/regularize_correlations_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/find_LTP_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/energy_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/apply_sine_window_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/wrappers_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/float/process_gains_FLP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/stereo_quant_pred.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/LPC_inv_pred_gain.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/process_NLSFs.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NSQ.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/check_control_input.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_del_dec_quant.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/LPC_analysis_filter.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/dec_API.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/sort.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/VAD.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_private_AR2.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/LPC_fit.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/control_SNR.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decode_parameters.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/pitch_est_tables.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/warped_autocorrelation_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/apply_sine_window_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy16_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/schur64_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/noise_shape_analysis_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/encode_frame_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/schur_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/find_LTP_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/find_LPC_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/corrMatrix_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/k2a_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/process_gains_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/k2a_Q16_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/regularize_correlations_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/vector_ops_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/find_pitch_lags_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/fixed/find_pred_coefs_FIX.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/control_audio_bandwidth.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decoder_set_fs.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_unpack.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/bwexpander.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_rom.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/shell_coder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decode_pulses.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/bwexpander_32.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decode_core.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/PLC.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_WB.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/table_LSF_cos.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_pulses_per_block.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_gain.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/inner_prod_aligned.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_down2_3.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NSQ_del_dec.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decode_pitch.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/interpolate.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/debug.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_other.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/LP_variable_cutoff.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_decode.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/encode_pulses.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/control_codec.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/stereo_LR_to_MS.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/HP_variable_cutoff.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/encode_indices.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/init_decoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/stereo_encode_pred.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_VQ.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/init_encoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_private_IIR_FIR.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_private_up2_HQ.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/sigm_Q15.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/sum_sqr_shift.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_LTP.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_down2.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/code_signs.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/gain_quant.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/tables_pitch_lag.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_stabilize.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/stereo_find_predictor.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/A2NLSF.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF2A.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/VQ_WMat_EC.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/NLSF_encode.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/log2lin.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/stereo_decode_pred.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/lin2log.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/CNG.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/enc_API.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/biquad_alt.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/quant_LTP_gains.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/resampler_private_down_FIR.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/ana_filt_bank_1.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/stereo_MS_to_LR.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/silk/decode_indices.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/rate.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/entdec.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/modes.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/celt_lpc.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/laplace.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/cwrs.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/celt.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/entcode.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/celt_decoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/celt_encoder.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/mdct.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/quant_bands.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/vq.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/bands.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/kiss_fft.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/entenc.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/mathops.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libopus/deps/opus/celt/pitch.o
npm ERR!   AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/opus.a
npm ERR!   COPY Release/opus.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opus/src/node-opus.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/build'
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26/opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.4.4
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.16.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26/opus.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.8.0/opus-v0.8.0-node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.8.0/opus-v0.8.0-node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @discordjs/opus@0.8.0 and node@16.16.0 (node-v93 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.8.0/opus-v0.8.0-node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ec2-user/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ec2-user/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c: In function ‘silk_autocorr’:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c:47:29: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_celt_autocorr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!      *scale = _celt_autocorr(inputData, results, NULL, 0, corrCount-1, inputDataSize, arch);
npm ERR!                              ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c:33:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/celt_lpc.h:63:5: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  int _celt_autocorr(const opus_val16 *x, opus_val32 *ac,
npm ERR!      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c:47:40: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘_celt_autocorr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!      *scale = _celt_autocorr(inputData, results, NULL, 0, corrCount-1, inputDataSize, arch);
npm ERR!                                         ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c:33:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/celt_lpc.h:63:5: note: expected ‘opus_val32 * {aka float *}’ but argument is of type ‘opus_int32 * {aka int *}’
npm ERR!  int _celt_autocorr(const opus_val16 *x, opus_val32 *ac,
npm ERR!      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c: In function ‘silk_burg_modified_c’:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c:98:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!              celt_pitch_xcorr(x_ptr, x_ptr + 1, xcorr, subfr_length - D, D, arch );
npm ERR!                               ^~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c:35:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c:98:37: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!              celt_pitch_xcorr(x_ptr, x_ptr + 1, xcorr, subfr_length - D, D, arch );
npm ERR!                                      ^~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c:35:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c:98:48: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!              celt_pitch_xcorr(x_ptr, x_ptr + 1, xcorr, subfr_length - D, D, arch );
npm ERR!                                                 ^~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c:35:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘opus_val32 * {aka float *}’ but argument is of type ‘opus_int32 * {aka int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c: In function ‘silk_pitch_analysis_core’:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:200:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!          celt_pitch_xcorr( target_ptr, target_ptr - MAX_LAG_4KHZ, xcorr32, SF_LENGTH_8KHZ, MAX_LAG_4KHZ - MIN_LAG_4KHZ + 1, arch );
npm ERR!                            ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:39:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:200:39: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!          celt_pitch_xcorr( target_ptr, target_ptr - MAX_LAG_4KHZ, xcorr32, SF_LENGTH_8KHZ, MAX_LAG_4KHZ - MIN_LAG_4KHZ + 1, arch );
npm ERR!                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:39:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:200:66: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!          celt_pitch_xcorr( target_ptr, target_ptr - MAX_LAG_4KHZ, xcorr32, SF_LENGTH_8KHZ, MAX_LAG_4KHZ - MIN_LAG_4KHZ + 1, arch );
npm ERR!                                                                   ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:39:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘opus_val32 * {aka float *}’ but argument is of type ‘opus_int32 * {aka int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c: In function ‘silk_P_Ana_calc_corr_st3’:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:616:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!          celt_pitch_xcorr( target_ptr, target_ptr - start_lag - lag_high, xcorr32, sf_length, lag_high - lag_low + 1, arch );
npm ERR!                            ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:39:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:616:39: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!          celt_pitch_xcorr( target_ptr, target_ptr - start_lag - lag_high, xcorr32, sf_length, lag_high - lag_low + 1, arch );
npm ERR!                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:39:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘const opus_val16 * {aka const float *}’ but argument is of type ‘const opus_int16 * {aka const short int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:616:74: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘celt_pitch_xcorr_c’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
npm ERR!          celt_pitch_xcorr( target_ptr, target_ptr - start_lag - lag_high, xcorr32, sf_length, lag_high - lag_low + 1, arch );
npm ERR!                                                                           ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c:39:0:
npm ERR! ../deps/opus/celt/pitch.h:185:1: note: expected ‘opus_val32 * {aka float *}’ but argument is of type ‘opus_int32 * {aka int *}’
npm ERR!  celt_pitch_xcorr_c(const opus_val16 *_x, const opus_val16 *_y,
npm ERR!  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: g++: Command not found
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/opus/src/node-opus.o] Error 127
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.130-118.517.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26/opus.node" "--module_name=opus" "--module_path=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26/opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.26 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:85:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.130-118.517.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/app/Discord_MultiPurpose/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.4.4
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2022-08-12T17_03_18_121Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Lot of text but the relevant part of the error is `make: g++: Command not found`. You need to install g++.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. That solved the issue. I'm very grateful you made my day :) how do I make it such that your comment is marked as an answer?